# Process freezes when using plotting with multiprocessing in Python

Tags: ubuntu, python, multiprocessor

I'm parallelizing a process by using the multiprocessing module. The function that is parallelized does plotting and using `savefig` module saves the plot in pdf format.

However, when the code is run, only one of the iterations results in an image while other images although created are of size 0 bytes.

The following error is thrown and the computer freezes:

```
Gdk-Message: 14:44:50.467: python2.7: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on a laptop with 4 cores.

Comment: Are you serializing communications with the X server? I suspect that the processes share a connection and the X protocol is being corrupted.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the display environment for all the processes is remaining the same viz. os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0', which is causing temporary resource (in this case, the display) unavailability. How do I obviate using the same display for such a multiprocessing job?

Comment: The issue isn't the display, it's the socket connecting your script to the X11 server. I don't know which X library you use, but if you open the socket (initialize the X library, perhaps) separately in each subprocess, that ought to take care of it.

Comment: How can I initialize the X11 server? I'm not sure if I'm correct, but I think my system is using `xorg` because I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. Could you provide how I could initialize the X library separately in each subprocess? I'm very new to this jargon, thank you for bearing with me.

Comment: Within python when I do the following: >>> import os; >>> os.system('Xorg'). This error results: `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server`

Comment: No, that's starting the X server itself.  I'm thinking of how your process connects to it, using the DISPLAY variable to find the server.  What's the first X-related call you make?  This might be buried in your graphing or user-interface module.